# Segue Not Showing Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, segue

I have 2 `ViewController`s that are presenting a new `ViewController`.

The first is in a navigation controller so it works as expected with a segue push.

The second however is from a `ViewController` without a navigation bar.  I'm programmatically presenting this view.  However when the destination is presented there are 2 issues...

1) There is no navigation bar.
2) The view shown starts below the first TableViewCell.

```
func goToLocation() {
    let locationTableVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "locationProfile") as! LocationTableViewController
    locationTableVC.documentId = selectedDocumentId!
    self.present(locationTableVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

LocationTableViewController.swift

```
// MARK: - View Will Appear
override public func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    // Make Nav Bar Translucent and Set title font/color
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "back-arrow-white")

}
```

[image]

Segue shows starting below the first TableViewCell and without a navigation bar.
[image: Segue shows starting below the first TableViewCell and without a navigation bar.]

The first segue which I'm trying to recreate like the second looks like this...
[image]

Comment: "1)" is easy, it doesn't have a navigation controller, because you don't have one from that view. You must push the view controller embedded in a UINavigationController to have one. It may also solve "2)" if it works when pushing from the other view.

Comment: @Daniel So if i didn't want to the navigation bar shown on the first VC though i'd just hide it?

Comment: You don't need to hide it, just create one when you need it. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Push your UIViewController with a UINavigationController, like this:

```
func goToLocation() {
    let locationTableVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "locationProfile") as! LocationTableViewController
    locationTableVC.documentId = selectedDocumentId!
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: locationTableVC)
    self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel that did solve #2 as well.  The only thing I need to do is set the back/dismiss button up as well.  Do I add this in the `goToLocation` function?  Or would this be in the `locationTableVC`?

Comment: It would be in the locationTableVC

Comment: This seems to override the other back button.  Because then I have to call a function and `popViewController` which works for the other view but for the ViewController coming from `goToLocation`

Comment: Thats right, you need an if to decide if you need to add that button or not

Comment: 100% otherwise there's no way to leave the VC